# ng-animate not working with ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-animate

I have ng-animate working on my ng-view; however, I can't seem to get it working for ng-show. I would like to fade in a sub-section inside the ng-view.

Here is my html:

```
<section id="content" ng-show="!isSpanish">   
   <item-list page="page" is-spanish="isSpanish" info="info" list="list" api="api" objects="objects"></item-list>
   <item-content page="page" staff="staff" info="info" blog-items="list" list="objects" api="api" overview="filteredOverview" is-spanish="isSpanish" partner="partner"></item-content>
</section>
```

Here is my css:

```
#content.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#content.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 5s;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}
```

Is there anything that would prevent this from working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My Solution in Daniles plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/By9sHjbAgtp5bmDHrRet?p=preview)

Note: I changed it to 5s so you could see the effect of the opacity of 0 when hidden. The nganimate toggles it to 1 via the show and vice versa. Once you see this you may change the ther transition properties freely.

Try this, add this below you css :

```
#content.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#content.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
   -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 5s;
   -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 5s;
   -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 5s;
   -o-transition: all ease-in-out 5s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 5s;  
}

#content.ng-hide {     
   line-height: 20px;
   -ms-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   padding: 0 0px;  
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Lemme see if I can set up a plunkr for you.

Comment: @KreepN I already set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R8bSiNCtf80jozznSZLS?p=preview) but you answered first :)

Comment: @Daniel Forked yours. See Edit. Lol, my bad on the steal. I appreciate it +1 to one of your quality posts.

Comment: @KreepN great, i'd just change the duration from 5s to 0.5s, it's way too long and makes the animation almost unnoticeable

Comment: thanks, I  must have something else going on in my code. no luck getting anything to work.

Comment: @byrdr Just to rule out, you did inject the ng-animate module (as it is a seperate module) to your app right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to css changes like this

```
#content.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#content.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px;
}

#content.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5p1QknN7CxZ020bfPX4E?p=preview)

Comment: @byrdr does it help full to you?